# How do I make packages out of non-package installers?

Tags: macos, install, remote-desktop

I want to use Apple Remote Desktop to install software on the Macs in our office, but often the installers come as an application bundle (not the actual application which could simply be copied, but an executable that has to be run). An example of this is Adobe Flash. Is there a way to convert or "wrap" this type of installer in a package so that ARD will recognise and be able to deploy them? (ARD only seems to recognise .pkg files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a first party Package Maker application available with Xcode. There's also [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html), a third party solution.

Comment: Thanks. I went with Packages as advised on a cross-post on the Apple Discussion Forums. I'll give you credit for this answer as I didn't get around to answering it myself before you did ;)